# How do I change password in windows server 2016 on the login screen?

Tags: windows-server, windows-server-2016

I just bought a hosted Windows 2016 server, and the only access I have to it right now is a god-awfull java-based KVM-interface.

In order to sign in, I need to enter my password, then I am prompted to change my password (first login) - and then I am presented with this screen:

[image]

It seems that no matter what I enter on this screen, I get told passwords do not match.

The top field labeled "Password" is pre-filled with a number of characters that corresponds to the current (initial) password.

Here is what I have tried:

1. In the "New password" field at the bottom, I have entered the current password again. => Passwords do not match.
2. I have tried clearing the top field and entering a new password, which I repeat in the below field. => Passwords do not match. I guarantee what I entered matched, and I tried several times. I tried 1234 as password, even clicked the little "reveal password" eye to see it was entered as expected - still got "The passwords you entered did not match". I also tried password that match the requirements.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: One possibility is that your entered password does not fulfill the password-complexity rules and so was ignored. Ask the provider of the hosted server for help, since he is responsible for this mess.

Comment: Can you provide us the full error you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the windows installation was corrupt. That was what caused this.